# Firebase JobDispatcher stops working after 1 hour

Tags: java, android

on API > 21 when my phone is locked this service is stop working (when I wake up a phone a service is starting working). This is what I do :

```
public class JobDispacherService extends JobService {

    private Preferences prefs = null;
    public static final String GCM_ONEOFF_TAG = "oneoff|[0,0]";
    public static final String GCM_REPEAT_TAG = "komunalRepeat|[7200,1800]";
    private static final String TAG = JobDispacherService.class.getSimpleName();
    private UplaudPossitionTask uplaudPossitionTask;

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(@NonNull JobParameters job) {

        uplaudPossitionTask = new UplaudPossitionTask() {
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                jobFinished(job, false);
            }
        };
        uplaudPossitionTask.execute();
        return false; // Answers the question: "Is there still work going on?"
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters job) {
        return true; // Answers the question: "Should this job be retried?"
    }

    private class UplaudPossitionTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            uploadPosition();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

And I call this service just like this :

```
  FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(context));

        Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                .setService(JobDispacherService.class)
                .setTag("my-unique-tag")
                .setRecurring(true)
                .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
                .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(10, (int) 15))
                .setReplaceCurrent(false)
                .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL)
                .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK)
                .build();

        dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
```

I want to repeat this time all the time and I do not have idea why this service is stop wrking when my phone is locked more than 1h

WorkManager :

```
public static void refreshCouponPeriodicWork() {

    //define constraints
    Constraints myConstraints = new Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiresDeviceIdle(false)
            .setRequiresCharging(false)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
            .setRequiresStorageNotLow(true)
            .build();

    Data source = new Data.Builder()
            .putString("workType", "PeriodicTime")
            .build();

    PeriodicWorkRequest refreshCpnWork =
            new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(RefreshLatestCouponWorker.class, 10, TimeUnit.HOURS,30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .setConstraints(myConstraints)
                    .setInputData(source)
                    .build();

    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(refreshCpnWork);
}


public class RefreshLatestCouponWorker extends Worker {

    private Preferences prefs = null;


    public RefreshLatestCouponWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Worker.Result doWork() {
        //read input argument
        String workType = getInputData().getString("workType");
        Log.i("refresh cpn work", "type of work request: " + workType);

        uploadPosition();
        //sending work status to caller
        return success();
    }

}
```

I do this for work manager but task run only once and never is repeating

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read about WorkManager, that will be the correct solution for you. The WorkManager API makes it easy to schedule deferrable, asynchronous tasks that are expected to run even if the app exits or device restarts. You can define Periodic requests with specified time interval and device state. Revert in case you  find the implementation difficult, i could help you with it.

Comment: Ok I try find this

Comment: I edit my post . I create a workManager but task run only once and never been repeat